# Counting peaks per group in gait data

Tags: python

So, I have gait data of 165 participants, 12k data per person, pretty big.

I want to calculate the amount of swings by counting the peaks in the mean force data of the left heel.
So far I have this code:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
z = df['mean_heel_l'][0:12118] # but I don't want to slice like this for ALL the data
peaks=find_peaks(z, height=100, width=10)
```

This works perfect for the 1st participant, but I have 165...

The only way I can group the data by participant is by using the filename:

```
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
z = df.groupby(['filename'])['mean_heel_l']
peaks=find_peaks(z, height=100, width=10)
```

But this results in the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Then I figured, maybe I can use the count of data per participant to select the data per participant

```
df.groupby(['filename'])[['mean_heel_l']].count()
```

Anyone an idea how I can do this?

Comment: I think you are on the right track with the middle approach.  Realize that when you use pandas `groupby` the returned object is a **collection** of `dataframe`s.  So you need to iterate over that collection or use one of the built in methods that works on the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a toy example working with groupby objects.  Plenty more examples on this site and with simple search:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
    ...:                     'value': [2.5, 3, 4.0, 1.1, 2.2]} 
    ...:                     )                                                  

In [29]: df                                                                     
Out[29]: 
  filename  value
0        a    2.5
1        a    3.0
2        a    4.0
3        b    1.1
4        b    2.2

In [30]: groups = df.groupby(['filename'])                                      

In [31]: for f_name, group in groups: 
    ...:     print(f'name of group: {f_name}') 
    ...:     print(group['value']) 
    ...:     print(max(group['value'])) 
    ...:     print() 
    ...:      
    ...:                                                                        
name of group: a
0    2.5
1    3.0
2    4.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
4.0

name of group: b
3    1.1
4    2.2
Name: value, dtype: float64
2.2
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure.  You can "accept" the answer if it was helpful.